# How to change back to my Apple ID for updates in App Store

Tags: apple-id, ipod

On my iPod 5G, I previously signed in on with fathers Apple ID. Now I have my own Apple ID and I can't change the iPod to use to mine.

Now when I download apps it shows mine but when I update it it shows my Dad's Apple ID.

How can I get my iPod to only use my Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

What ever was downloaded under your Dads Apple ID stays his.

Any app download under his Apple ID will continue updates under his Apple ID. You can not change that.

Sign out of your Dads Apple ID.

In order to change that and have your apps, you need to use your Apple ID and re-download stuff to be yours from now on, including updates to your apple id.

Applications from appstore are Apple ID associated.

Simply stated: Delete all apps that were downloaded under your Dads Apple id and download them again under your ID.

Comment: No any app I update it shows my dads Apple id I want to log off his and sign in to mine

Comment: You can't simply transfer ownership, it doesn't work that way. If you want rid of the old ID you need to delete any apps that belong to him & buy them again, as this answer says - or use Family Sharing, as the other answer says.

Comment: But I hae data on the apps

Answer (score 0):

If you convince him to activate Family Sharing —and invite you— you can use the apps bought originally with his Apple ID with your own Apple ID.

Data associated with his Apple ID will probably be lost on this setting (i.e. game progress, in app upgrades).